# Opening file from filemanager as a full window

Tags: emacs

When opening a file in emacs using Window Explorer or GNOME Nautilus File, the file opened in split view and the bottom window contain the emacs welcome screen.

Is there any way that the file opens as a single window and remaining buffer like *scratch", *message* etc remains open but hidden.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that behaviour permanently you can use:

```lisp
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'delete-other-windows)
```

in your emacs-initialization.

Comment: Currently I am using ubuntu 13.10, and after adding the setting I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Could you try `/usr/bin/emacs -Q --eval "(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'delete-other-windows)"` on the command line?

Comment: It's working from command line. Can you please help me getting the same result when opening from file manager. Thanks

Comment: It depends on how the manager calls `emacs` or `emacsclient`. Can you find out that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it for Ubuntu:
Write to file `/usr/local/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacsclient
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=View and edit files
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=/usr/local/bin/emacsclient %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
```

Just make sure that `emacsclient` is indeed located in `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient`
(you can use `which emacsclient` in bash to see this).
Then execute from bash:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Finally, add to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'server)
(or (server-running-p) (server-start))
```

After this, once an Emacs instance is running, clicking on a file in Nautilus
will open it in the current window of Emacs, without changing the window configuration.

Comment: you could try `/usr/bin/emacsclient %F -a ""` without modifying `.emacs`. If it fails; put the command `exec /usr/bin/emacsclient "$@" -a ""` in a shell script and exec that. It should start the server if it is not running. You could put the file into `~/.local/share/applications` to avoid modifying a system-wide location.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the function `display-buffer` (or its related family of functions, e.g., `pop-to-buffer`) defaults to a split-window if no other settings control the window / frame selection.  If you have further problems, one of your initial buffer choices is likely using something like that -- or you have a `display-buffer-alist` setting which is causing it.

Using `(setq initial-buffer-choice t)` will eliminate the Welcome screen and leave you with just a `*scratch*` buffer.

I use this in my Emacs setup file:

```lisp
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)

(setq initial-buffer-choice t)
```

---

Depending upon whether you have `desktop-save-mode` active, you may need something like this also . . . I have modified the `desktop-read` function so that I can use it subsequent to the `after-init-hook` (which loads before the `emacs-startup-hook`).

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
  (bury-buffer "*scratch*") ))
```